# Call more than 1 $rootScope.$on

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

Hey I am trying to execute one portion of code only if there is 2 `$broadcast` event, this is what I got.

In my controller1 I have this.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('receivedData');
```

In my controller2

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('dataLoaded');
```

So far I have this.

```
$rootScope.$on('dataLoaded',function(){
    $http({
       url:"http://api/data",
       method:"POST",
       data:{id_cliente: parseInt(getVariable("id"))},
       headers:{
             "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8",
             "Authorization" : "Bearer " + getVariable("token")
     }
   })
     .then(function(response){
           setVariable("contratos", JSON.stringify(response.data));
           $rootScope.$broadcast("cargaContratos");

   },
     function(response){
     });
})
```

And I have to execute this only if `recievedData` and `dataLoaded` are triggered. Anybody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
var received = [];

$rootScope.$on('receivedData', function() {
    received.push('receivedData');
    doSomething();
})
$rootScope.$on('dataLoaded', function() {
    received.push('dataLoaded');
    doSomething();
})

doSomething() {
    if (received.indexOf('receivedData') > -1 && received.indexOf('dataLoaded') > -1) {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

---

I'd recommend using services/promises though, AngularJS has a promise library included by default: [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). Then, you can simply use `$q.all()`. But for now, this should work fine.

---

## Update (promise example)

Actually, you already use a promise (`$http`), which enables a callback with `then()`.

Here is a (copy-pastable) example of a simple promise setup. You should try it out:

Service:

```
app.service('promiseTest', function($q) {
    this.myPromise = function() {
        return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                resolve('hello!');
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
})
```

Component/Controller:

```
app.controller('promiseTestCtrl', function(promiseTest) {
    promiseTest.myPromise().then(function(msg) {
        console.log(msg)
    })
})
```

I recommend playing around with them to understand them better.

When both calls are converted to a promise, you can then use:

```
var promises = [myService.receivedData, myService.dataLoaded];

$q.all(promises).then(function() {
    // Your code
})
```

Comment: I'll try it, but can you give me an example of how to use promises in this case (noob to AngularJS).

Comment: Here you go. I *really* recommend reading more about promises though before you're going to use them, but if you understand how they work, it'll really help you with asynchronous stuff.

Comment: I will read the docs, looks may more better with promises. Thanks a lot.